# Sling Rewriter to change the static resource URL

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling, aem-6

We have used sling rewriter in our project to transform the resource URL's with static domains defined in our OSGI configuration. This is working fine for the tags defined in the include tags property in component. For eg- For style tag and when attribute is data-role. It transforms the url as expected-

But for below case the url for background:url needs to be transformed. Instead of being picked from localhost it should transform it to static url mentioned in OSGI config-

```
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.lazy-bg--4021ca1508b28f815a670f961c7fcba6 {
background:url(http://localhost:4512/content/dam/unilever/magnum/spain/static_not_in-use_products_/magnum_vegan_key_visual_green_classic_2880x1200_72dpi-1395468-jpg.jpg.ulenscale.1500x649.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
  }
}
```

As background:url is not an attribute of style tag here, so url is not getting transformed.
Can you please provide some inputs?

Comment: I think that is the way Sling Re-writer works, it rewrites HTML attributes only. Have a look at [this link](https://cqdump.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/resource-path-vs-url-and-rewriting-links/) for more options.

Comment: We would need further infos to help you. 1) Are you talking about a html- or an css file (by default only html files are rewritten). 2) How you implemented it? I assume it is based on org.apache.sling.rewriter.DefaultTransformer. 3) Best-guess answer: It is a SAX content handler. So everything is there - but only html is fully parsed by the SAX parser. The css inside <style> block is just a big text-content. Then you have to parse the CSS or just search/replace the URL manually.

Comment: That means Sling re-writer won't work for background:url?

Comment: You can rewrite the background url. But in your SAX ContentHandler you have to check by yourself, when you are inside a <style> element. Then you have to search/replace inside the characters(...) callback. If you are using the DefaultTransformer, then you have to re-implement the characters(...)-method.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the rewriter is only processing a configured set of attributes, you will need to map this resource path manually (using the resource resolver api).